# how to make json string by using php array?

Tags: php, arrays, json

**This is the target jason string:**

```
{"dpid": 272, "priority": 10, "match": {"nw_src": "192.168.1.1", "nw_dst": "192.168.1.2", "nw_proto": 1, "eth_type": 0x0800}, "actions":[{"type": "DROP"}]}
```

**This is the php array that i made:**

```
$rule = array(
  "dpid" => 272,
  "priority" => 10,
  "match" => {"nw_src": "$_POST['src']", "nw_dst": "$_POST['dst']", "nw_proto": 1, "eth_type": 0x0800},
  "actions"=> [{"type": "DROP"}],  
);
```

i am trying to turn this array into the json string above, using:

```
$data_string=json_encode( $rule );
```

but it doesnt work :(

i know the array is really non-sense, i am really new to php. Could somebody help me?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on "but it doesn't work"? Are you getting an error? The wrong results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your array should be:

```
$rule = array(
    "dpid" => 272,
    "priority" => 10,
    "match" => array(
        "nw_src" => $_POST['src'], 
        "nw_dst" => $_POST['dst'], 
        "nw_proto" => 1, 
        "eth_type" => 0x0800 
    ),
    "actions"=> array(array("type" => "DROP")),  
);
```

After that `json_encode` function will do all the work for you:

```
$data_string = json_encode($rule);
```

Comment: op's `actions` is an array of object not object itself.